# Change main partition size to install another distribution

Tags: partition

I have CentOS 5.5 installed, I have no un-partitioned space and the only ext3 partition I have is huge with lots of free space.

Can I change that partition size in order to allocate another one? I want to create new partitions in order to install another distribution there (Ubuntu).

I tried to do it through the volume administration tool in CentOS, but when I edit the partition size and confirm, it says that it is mounted in / and it needs to be un-mounted before re-sizing, which of course fails.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably look at [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/); as long as you're working in Gnome it'll work without data loss. If not, there's a LiveCD/media version which lets you boot and reconfigure without involving the current OS.

Something to consider for future system setups is using LVM ([**man** page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvm), [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management), [additional detailed reference](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/lvm.html)), which allows this kind of reallocation on the fly without special software. I'm pretty sure you can't convert an existing filesystem to LVM without rebuilding it. I use LVM on one of my home systems, and it makes adding additional physical drives pretty trivial - they just get added to the volume group, and then I allocate as needed.

Comment: Thanks! Great info. Please edit your answer to add some LVM link (I had to google it).

Comment: @Toto - I added the links. Sorry I didn't add them initially; for some reason I was convinced I was too new a user to be able to add more than one link. Oops :)

Comment: GParted has nothing to do with Gnome except for using gnome libraries; what did you have in mind with the data loss remark?

Comment: @Gilles - apologies for the poor phrasing; I was attempting to convey what you stated, in that you have to have Gnome on your system to use GParted without using the media-based version.

Comment: The rep limit is only 10 for posting multiple links, and I think it's actually 1 during beta, so you're good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

The smart and safe thing to do is to boot from a live CD and resize from the CD since the partition does not have to be mounted in that case.

Parted magic is a live CD especially made to repartition drives.

PS Take the LVM suggestion with a grain of salt. For me LVM seems to use a lot of resources.
Of course YMMV.

Comment: I do recommend LVM for ease of management. I've never come upon any performance impact of LVM: could you elaborate on your experience (ideally with some hard data)?