# shrinking partition containing root filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, partition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change main partition size to install another distribution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/change-main-partition-size-to-install-another-distribution)

[image]

this is the image showing partitions on my hard drive. I am reading [linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) and so i need to create a dedicated partition to make my machine. sda1 is alloted to root but it uses only 3.45 GB of about 15 GB. Rest ~ 11GB is free. So, I need to shrink sda1 and make a dedicated partition. This is my only option as only 1 MB is free on the disk and i need approx 3 GB. So, i searched and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28122/can-i-resize-the-root-partition-without-uninstalling-and-reinstalling-linux-or) but can i shrink a partition by this method? If not, then please tell how to do that?

Note: I have backed up my files on ubuntu one cloud. So, backup shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I love using the LiveCD distro called [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) for doing this job. It will provide you with a nice GUI interface with a slider bar that you can manipulate to resize the disks.

**Beware**, modifying partition sizes could have devastating effects. Since you have done a backup, it is less of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

The link you refer to is not applicable because it's using LVM and you aren't.

Basically, you can do what you want, but you need to have booted from a LiveCD since you can't decrease the size of the root partition while Linux is using it. Tim's recommendation is probably OK as it's a custom resizing solution.